# How to copy a canvas into a bitmap

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to copy the contents of a canvas I have just drawn onto, into a bitmap?

**EDIT:** just to clarify, my current drawing procedure works as follows:

```
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

if (canvas != null)
{
  onDraw(canvas); // this does all the drawing

  // at this point I would like to copy the canvas into a bitmap

  holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); // this makes the canvas visible to the user
}
```

**EDIT:** Looking at the first answer posted, I have written the following code:

```
if (grab_screen == -1) // draw and show on screen as normal
{
    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    if(canvas != null)
    {
        onDraw(canvas);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }                   
}
else // draw into screengrab_bitmap[grab_screen]
{
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screengrab_bitmap[grab_screen]);
    onDraw(canvas);
    grab_screen = -1;
}
```

This should mean that if I set grab_screen to n, then on the next call to onDraw, the image will be written to screengrab_bitmap[n].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an "empty" Bitmap, assign it to a Canvas (new Canvas(newBitmap) ),draw  things in that canvas. Everything you draw on the Canvas will be drawn in the bitmap.

Comment: Looks good. Presumably I won't simultaneously see the drawing done by onDraw (see my edits). And what about the unlockCanvasAndPost?  I presume that I should simply not call it.

Comment: Take a look,maybe help: http://javafriend.yolasite.com/myandroid/saving-bitmap-from-surface-view   http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-saving.html